# Bash command to move and change current directory to it

Tags: bash, function

I need a bash command to move a directory somewhere else and change the current directory to it. Something simple like `mvcd`

I tried with

```
mvcd () {
  mv "$1" "$2"
  cd "$2"
}
```

but mv:

```
rename samples-folder to /Users/user/work/samples-folder: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How and where are you calling the function?

Comment: Is a bash function. Put it into `.zshrc` and call it, simple

Comment: Welcome, show the content of the variables `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: And how exactly is it being run? What arguments are you giving it? I can't reproduce it not working. Putting the function in `.bashrc` and entering two arguments for the name of the directory and the new name works with it changing to the new directory.

Comment: @NasirRiley  I suspect variable `$1` is not a full path.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I suspect something along those lines or something else. That's why I want to see exactly how it's being run and what's being entered because that still wouldn't explain the error.

Comment: Does the path `/Users/user/work` exist?

Comment: I'd use `mv "$@"; cd "${@: -1}";` However, that will still not work with `mv -t TARGET ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Your command should work fine. I guess your target directory `/Users/user/work/` does not exist.

However, your script could be enhanced:

- Accept any number of `mv` arguments, setting `TARGET` to last argument --> `${@: -1}`.
- Parse arguments and evaluate `-t TARGET` format, overwriting `TARGET`.
- If `TARGET` is a file name, the script should `cd` to it's path (`${TARGET%/*}`) instead.

```bsh
mvcd() {
  mv "$@" || return 1
  TARGET="${@: -1}"
  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
      case $1 in
          -t|--target-directory)
            TARGET="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
          --)
            break
            ;;
          *)
            shift
            ;;
      esac
  done
  if [ -d "$TARGET" ]; then
      cd "$TARGET"
  elif [ -f "$TARGET" ]; then
      cd "${TARGET%/*}"
  else
      printf 'ERROR: %s does not exist\n' "$TARGET"
  fi
}
```

You will need `bash` version > `4.1` I guess.

Comment: Nice. For completeness, you should probably add `--) break;;` to the `case` statement.

Comment: thanks, added !

Comment: Maybe adding a test for argument `$1`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity What test do you mean? If `mv` fails, the funtion will quit  (`|| return 1`). That should be enough I think.

Comment: @pLumo I mean to print an error if the source directory doesn't exist, like you do with the target.

Comment: @pLumo Ok, I misunderstood :)